# Lightswitch Authentication issue

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a Visual Studio 2012 Lightswitch desktop app that needs to run some code right after the user logs in, but before the home screen is displayed.

So I put the code in the Application_LoggedIn method.

I checked the this.AuthenticationService.User and verified that the user was logged in.

However when I run

```
DataWorkspace dw = this.CreateDataWorkspace();

 if(dw.ApplicationData.ApplicationSettingsSet.FirstOrDefault() == null)
 {
 .
 .
 .
```

I am invariably asked for credentials, with a pop up window.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Application.Current.CreateDataWorkspace
```

I've used it in Application_LoggedIn to log to a table who has logged into the application.

Comment: In the context it's in, the this keyword is referring to Application.Current

Comment: hi Yann , can you please explain the Application_LoggedIn method or any refrence for this method. Thanks

Comment: i am trying to add log like "      Private Sub Application_LoggedIn()

            Dim A = Application.Current.CreateDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.Logtable.AddNew()
            A.name = User.Name
            A.time = DateTime.Now
            A.dates = DateTime.Now.Date
            A.Activity = "Login"
            Application.Current.CreateDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.SaveChanges()

        End Sub    " but it does not working.

Comment: See my answer in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190939/form-authentication-and-active-users-in-lightswitch-web-app).